# How to make iterations using v-for directive on nested array (array in array)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I am new to Vue and I came upon a situation that I would like to have some advice on.

In my js file I have some arrays that contain some data that I would like to insert in a table:

```
const d1=[{col1:"aaa1",col2:"bbb1",col3:"ccc1",col4:"ddd1",col5:"eee1"},
          {col1:"aaa2",col2:"bbb2",col3:"ccc2",col4:"ddd2",col5:"eee2"}]
const d2=[{col1:"fff1",col2:"ggg1",col3:"hhh1",col4:"iii1",col5:"jjj1"},
          {col1:"aaa2",col2:"bbb2",col3:"ccc2",col4:"ddd2",col5:"eee2"}]
```

then I saved the two arrays in another variable called availableData

```
const availableData=[d1,d2];
```

my vue instance as follows:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#c1',
  data: {
    availableData,
  }
});
```

In my HTML I am trying to add a for loop(v-for) in my row div so the row can display each of data in my availableData variable, but I am having some problems trying to pass d1 to the first row and d2 to the second,

```
<div id="c1" class="columns">

// ...some code

    <div class="row" v-for="data in availableData">
        <div class="cell">
            {{data.col1}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{data.col2}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{data.col3}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{data.col4}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{data.col5}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, the v-for statement is not correct since I am trying to iterate through the availableData array, if I were to write

```
v-for="data in availableData[i]"
```

then is there a way to pass a varaible like i to achieve iteration, or is this method not a plausible way to conduct?

Comment: Try **[...d1, ...d2]** for **availableData**; your availableData now holds two arrays of objects instead of four objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several solutions to do what you want.

**Solution # 1 :**

You can alter the availableData to display all data like you want. You have just to flat you array like this :  `const availableData=[...d1, ...d2];`

With such a code your availableData variable will have :

```
const availableData = [{col1:"aaa1",col2:"bbb1",col3:"ccc1",col4:"ddd1",col5:"eee1"},
          {col1:"aaa2",col2:"bbb2",col3:"ccc2",col4:"ddd2",col5:"eee2"},
          {col1:"fff1",col2:"ggg1",col3:"hhh1",col4:"iii1",col5:"jjj1"},
          {col1:"aaa2",col2:"bbb2",col3:"ccc2",col4:"ddd2",col5:"eee2"}]
```

**Solution # 2**

You can make a double iteration in your template :

```
<div class="data" v-for="data in availableData">
    <div class="row" v-for="row in data">
        <div class="cell">
            {{row.col1}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{row.col2}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{row.col3}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{row.col4}}
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            {{row.col5}}
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble with solution 2, {{row.col1}} , {{row.col2}}....in their respective divs did not display

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advice, I was able to accomplish the 2nd solution by not using the index at all, the div in the outside I wrote <div class="row" v-for="data in availableData"> and the 2nd layer I wrote <div class="row" v-for="row in data">, then I was able to make the {{row.col1}} , {{row.col1}} ... display, would you like to confirm or provide info on why adding index doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: You're right ! I'll correct that. You don't need to use index ! Good job !